# Ending of "messages" exchanged between client and server sockets

Tags: java, sockets, winsock

**Java server socket**

In the following code:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KnockKnockServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

when the server sends its response to the client socket, it writes to the "PrintWriter" "out" using the "println()" method (line 63).

- I have tried using the "print()" method instead.
- In the "println()" case, the client socket receives the message properly.
- In the "print()" case, the client socket doesn't receive anything.
- Is this normal?
- Is it required to send an `EOF`, a `CR LF` (in my case) (10 and 13 ASCII characters) at the end of the message?
- Is it documented somewhere?

**Winsock**

In the following code: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

the "send()" method is used.

- Does it implicitly send an EOF (a CR LF sequence for example) to the server socket at the end of the message passed as an argument?
- Is it documented somewhere?
- Is it part of the socket implementation?
- Note that, I am not adding a EOF (CR LF for example) at the end of the message.
- I'm ending the message with a trailing '\0' character.

When a "message" (an array of characters) is sent from a socket endpoint to another socket endpoint, does the message have to be ended with some kind of EOF? It appears to me now that it doesn't.

Comment: Did you flush the writer in the second case?

Comment: In the Winsock case? What should I flush and how (please refer to the code I'm linking to)? Can you explain why it would be useful?

Comment: Can the person who wants this question to be closed justify itself? And also the one who downvoted? That could maybe help me.

Comment: Code and error messages that form part of a question must be included in the question itself. Otherwise it has no permanent value here.

Comment: Ok. I copied and pasted without any modification the code from the links I mentioned into my post. I have no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general need to send an EOF sign in java socket communication, BUT 
if your client uses InputStream.readLine() to read the servers answer, than this is normal, because
readLine() blocks until a line has been completely read (until \n \r or \r\n found) or the socket is closed by the server.
But in this example, the socket is not closed by the server, because the server is waiting for the clients answer and if the client is waiting for the end of line, you have a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> when the server sends its response to the client socket, it writes to the "PrintWriter" "out" using the "println()" method

`PrintWriter` is line buffered. See the Javadoc.

> I have tried using the "print()" method instead.

If you don't write a line it won't flush. Call `flush()` afterwards. But you shouldn't use `PrintWriter` over a network, as it swallows exceptions you need to know about. Use `BufferedWriter`.

> In the "println()" case, the client socket receives the message properly.

Because it's line-buffered, so there was an auto-flush.

> In the "print()" case, the client socket doesn't receive anything.

Because it's line-buffered so there wasn't an auto-flush.

> Is this normal?

Yes.

> Is it required to send an EOF, a CR LF (in my case) (10 and 13 ASCII characters) at the end of the message?

No.

> Is it documented somewhere?

Yes, in the Javadoc for `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for these explanations. I replaced the "PrintWriter" with a "BufferedWriter" in the server socket code. I'm using that kind of code now: BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())); bufferedWriter.write(writeTo); bufferedWriter.flush(); where "writeTo" is for example a char array.